# How to place 3d objects behind each other?

Tags: javafx

I originally wrote a program that generates an area of ​​2D rectangles. SUDDENLY, I wanted to arrange an isometric projection. I thought that the easiest way to do this is using 3D rectangles. I adapted the code and in general everything turned out the way I wanted. However, there was a problem that I do not know how to solve. Each new rectangle is placed as if on top of the rest. Because of what appears the effect of the relief of the area. I would like the platform to be flat. Below on the screen you will understand everything.
[image: two muppets]
I tried to experiment with setTranslateZ(), but it has no effect at all.

```
protected List fillingArea()
{
    manyPlacedSquares.add(new CustomBox(100,50,100, 0, 0, 0));
    for(int y = 0; y < numberOfSquares; y++)
    {
        for(CustomBox i: manyPlacedSquares)
        {
            CustomBox upBox = new CustomBox(100,50,100,i.getTranslateX()+70,i.getTranslateY()-50, i.getTranslateZ()-1 );
            manyPotentialSquares.add(upBox);
            CustomBox rightBox = new CustomBox(100,50,100,i.getTranslateX()-70,i.getTranslateY()-50,i.getTranslateZ()-1);
            manyPotentialSquares.add(rightBox);
            CustomBox belowBox = new CustomBox(100,50,100,i.getTranslateX()+70,i.getTranslateY()+50,i.getTranslateZ()-1);
            manyPotentialSquares.add(belowBox);
            CustomBox leftBox = new CustomBox(100,50,100,i.getTranslateX()-70,i.getTranslateY()+50,i.getTranslateZ()-1);
            manyPotentialSquares.add(leftBox);
        }
        System.out.println(manyPotentialSquares.size());
        System.out.println(manyPlacedSquares.size());
        System.out.println(manyPotentialSquares.get(1).getTranslateX());
        manyPotentialSquares.removeAll(manyPlacedSquares);
        System.out.println(manyPotentialSquares.size());
        index = randomGenerator.nextInt(manyPotentialSquares.size());
        manyPlacedSquares.add(manyPotentialSquares.get(index));
    }
    return manyPlacedSquares;
}
```

The custom box has plain content and is unlikely to be needed, but just in case, I'll show its content. equals () method redefined for correct operation removeall ()

```
public class CustomBox extends Box {
    Double tt;
    Double tt1;
    public CustomBox(double width, double height, double depth, double gtx, double gty, double gtz) 
        {
            super(width, height, depth);
            this.setTranslateX(gtx);
            this.setTranslateY(gty);
            this.setTranslateZ(gtz);
            tt = gtx;
            tt1 = gty;
        }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if(this.tt.equals(((CustomBox) obj).getTranslateX()) && this.tt1.equals(((CustomBox) obj).getTranslateY()))
        {
            System.out.println(tt + "  " + ((CustomBox) obj).getTranslateX());
            return true;
        }
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
           return false;
}


}
```

Comment: Can you show how you create the scene and the camera?

Comment: @JoséPereda um ... I just put them in a knot, as happens with 2D rectangles. The fact is that I do not need a 3D camera. I just want an isometric effect. I thought that the easiest way is to use 3d shapes. Pane root = new Pane();
        for(Box i: storage)
        {
            i.getTransforms().addAll(rxBox,ryBox,rzBox);
            root.getChildren().add(i);
        }

Comment: can I just remove the light source so that all this is in one color? but then the isometric effect will disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure JavaFX to use 3D correctly. Especially you have to switch depth buffering on. This is explained in the accepted answer of this question here: [Overlaping Shapes - wrong overlapping shapes behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589210/overlaping-shapes-wrong-overlapping-shapes-behaviour)

Comment: Thanks I got it. I will try to build a rectangle in 3D correctly, and then transfer this principle to my code.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, I did it all. [link](https://ibb.co/k1LZXFj) now everything looks right!